# How to set up dual monitor on PC without graphic card? Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, display

My PC does have built-in graphic. I have vga switch and using it I would like to setup dual monitor.  After pluging both monitors with VGA switch I had a duplicated view on both desktops. I would like to have extended view (mouse coursor goes between two desktops). Displays Settings does not show second monitor. How to setup it? How to make them two working in extended mode.

Before VGA switch I tried with DPI-DVI adapter, I was lucky to have extended mode on dual monitor but mouse cursor cannot go to second monitor - it was stick to the edge.

I've searched for solution to this problem many times. I've tried with xrandr, CCSM and many others, but nothing worked.

lspci | grep -E "VGA"

VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

Comment: You absolutely need a second video card to do that.

Comment: Doesn't VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) have any option to set up second monitor without video card?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you're splitting the output of one VGA connector on your PC, you can't - this (fairly obviously) just duplicates the signal to different monitors.

If you have a VGA connector and an HDMI or DVI connector, then you may be able to use dual monitors, depending on the graphics chipset. I don't recall ever seeing a motherboard with onboard graphics that had two video outputs, though.

Comment: Could you help me with my settings? lspci | grep -E "VGA"

VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09). When I use dvi-dpi adapter to plug second monitor mouse cursor on second monitor is sticked to the edge.

Comment: Have you tried turning off the "Sticky edges" option in Display settings? (In 12.04 at least, click the top-right-hand 'system' menu, then displays .. the option is near the bottom ..)

Even with that on the edges should only be a "little" sticky, though!

Comment: Tried. Still mouse cursor is sticked to the edge.

Comment: Does the display settings dialog show your monitors the right way around? If the left and right are confused that might explain what you're seeing!

Comment: Yes. It is OK. Monitors are not confused.

Answer (score 0):

In theory it is possible, but you'll need additional hardware anyway and your graphics adapter should be able to handle the extra resolution. You'll need a splitter that is plugged to your video output and have two outputs for two monitors. Most of these, the cheap ones, will just split the same output between two displays BUT there are others more expensive that will send half of the horizontal resolution to each monitor. This one for example:

http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/

What they do, I think, is that the device pretends to be an ultra-wide monitor display itself with a resolution of say 3840x1080 pixels, so the computer thinks there is just one display of such resolution plugged in, but the device then sends the first 1920x1080 pixels to one of the displays, and the rest to the other.

If you are using a normal desktop computer, it may be better to purchase a second graphics adapter which have some extra advantages because this way you have more control about what you want to see in each display. But if you are using a laptop, a barebone, a Mac Mini, or some other computer in which you cannot plug an extra video card and you really need a second display, it is a reliable option.

Alternatively, depending on your needs an ultra-wide monitor with a native resolution of 3840x1080 or so could be a better solution. They're usually expensiver than two monitors that put the same resolution together, though.

Finally, you could also purchase an USB driven vga adapter, it is actually a graphic card but you can plug in into an USB port instead of having to mount it inside the computer.